# Springboot with multiple filters

Tags: spring-boot, filter, websecurity

I am using spring boot and integrated Azure AD. For that, I have used `AADAuthenticationFilter`.

In my **WebSecurityConfig** which extends **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** I have written:

> http.addFilterBefore(aadAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

***How to add one more filter before executing the above line, for doing some custom filtering?***

Comment: is your question resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) annotation.

The value `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` can be used for overriding the highest priority among components.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
```

Or you could control order at a more controlled way, like for the first one:

> @Order(1)

For second:

> @Order(2)

Useful reference:

- [@Order in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-order)
- [How to define Spring Boot filter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter)